# sh 1 sudo not found python script done on ubuntu does not work on bananian

Tags: python, sh, sudo, raspbian, banana-pi

I made a script on ubuntu and now I want it to run on my banana pi with bananian (raspbian for banana pi).
Here is the part where of my script I have some problems:

```
foundmob= False
foundusb= False

sudoPassword='figaro'#my sudo password
command="usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 1f01 -M '55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000'" # the command that for ce the modem to be on serial mode
while foundusb!= True : # this allows me to look for the modem as an usb and then force it

    foundmob=terminalComAndRead("lsusb",'12d1:1f01')#doing a ls usb and then looking for the id of my device
    changemob=terminalComAndRead("lsusb",'12d1:1001')#this is the id of my device when it is already in serial mode

    if foundmob == True :

        os.system('echo %s|sudo -S %s' % (sudoPassword, command))# this is the line who execute the command on sudo
```

While I execute this script in ubuntu, I do not have any problem, but then when I want to execute it on bananian with my banana pi, I get this error:

> sh: 1: sudo: not found

It seems that the error comes from this line:

```
os.system('echo %s|sudo -S %s' % (sudoPassword, command))# this is the line who execute the command on sudo
```

So tried to run it on sudo and in another log in (not sudo). But still it does not work. Anybody has an idea? Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe sudo it's not in PATH or not installed. [Have you verified it](https://github.com/LeMaker/WiringBP/issues/3)?

Comment: you are right! but I thought I had used sudo before in the terminal. Like sudo apt-get... But anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That error message is saying that the python script can't find the `sudo` command. Does the bananian install have a `sudo` command? Do you need `sudo` to get the privileges you need for the `usb_modeswitch` command?

Comment: I think I do. This part of the script, I did it on my ubuntu, and I remember that I needed to use sudo to do that. thank you